# Clarification regarding IO::Select

Tags: perl

I am using [`IO::Select`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Select).

I didn't expect this code to terminate only when I manually kill the forked process. Is this correct behavior?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

STDOUT->autoflush();

use IO::Select;

open(my $ph, "-|", "perl -e 'sleep 1 while 1'");

my $sel = IO::Select->new();

$sel->add($ph);

$sel->can_read(2) or warn "timeout\n";

print "woohoo?\n";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html),

> Closing any piped filehandle causes the parent process to wait for the child to finish, then returns the status value in `$?` and `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`.

So closing the file handle in `$ph` (which is done when `$ph` goes out of scope) waits for the child to complete.

(This has nothing to do with IO::Select or `select`.)

Comment: Is `IO::Select` with timeout suitable for `STDOUT` monitoring of long living PIDs?

Comment: @Сухой27, I'm not sure what you mean by "STDOUT monitoring".

Comment: I mean monitoring output of forked process, ie. wait for output for few sec, then do something else, then wait again, etc.

Comment: Yes, but not on Windows. (`select` only works on sockets in Windows, so you'd simply use a socket (e.g. created using `socketpair`) instead of pipe there.) Note that most programs do full buffering of STDOUT when it's connected to a pipe.